# Flutter: Como mantener un FAB encima de un DraggableScrollableSheet

Tags: flutter, dart

Tengo un layout con un FloatingActionButton (FAB) y un DraggableScrollableSheet (DSS). Si arrastro el DSS, el FAB se mantiene siempre en la misma posición.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que el FAB permanezca arriba del DSS cuando arrastro el DSS?

**Ejemplo de Google Maps:**

[image: Posición 1]

[image: Posición 2]

Answer (score 0):

Al final lo he resuelto de la siguiente manera:

He puesto el DraggableScrollableSheet dentro de un NotificationListener de tipo DraggableScrollableNotification. De esta manera puedo saber la extensión que ocupa en cada momento y usar esa extensión como margen inferior del FAB.

```
NotificationListener<DraggableScrollableNotification>(
            child: DraggableScrollableSheet(
              builder: (context, ScrollController controller) {
                return SingleChildScrollView(
                  controller: controller,
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    height: 300,
                  ),
                );
              },
              initialChildSize: 0.2,
              maxChildSize: 1,
              minChildSize: 0,
              expand: true,
            ),
            onNotification: (notificacion) {
              print(notificacion.extent);
              double heightSheet = notificacion.extent;
              setState(() {
                marginFab = heightScreen * heightSheet;
              });
              return true;
            },
          )
```